# Joining two polygons where they overlap the most in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have two layers: district (with lots of districts) and an object layer.
I want to add the information where the object lies in the most to the object.

For example: this object lies the most in district B, so it should add 'B' to a column in the objects attribute table.

[image]

I tried spatial joins but i am not getting what i am searching for.

Does anyone know how to get there?

Comment: Thanks worked great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume there are two polygon layers one called *'grid_test'* (green) and the second called *'grid_test2'* (orange), see image below.

[image: input]

Apply the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) tool with the *2 — Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one-to-one)* for the *'Join type'*:

[image: settings]

and get the output like this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

Use QGIS expressions with this expression:

```
array_first (
    overlay_intersects( 
        'Districts',  -- Replace with the name of the layer
        $id,
        sort_by_intersection_size:='des'
    )
)
```

The parameter `sort_by_intersection_size` works since QGIS 3.24, see [visual changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-overlay-intersects-sort-by-intersection-size).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked also great!